Prove $Pr[Z \leq 0, -\ln{\tanh{\frac{-Z}{2}}} \leq x] = Pr[Z \geq -\ln{\tanh{\frac{x}{2}}}]$ for any random variable $Z$ and non-negative constant $x$
I am reading an article (Design of capacity-approaching irregular low-density parity-check codes, Richardson et al.) and I stumbled upon the following claim:
$Pr[Z \geq 0, -\ln{\tanh{\frac{Z}{2}}} \leq x] = Pr[Z \geq -\ln{\tanh{\frac{x}{2}}}]$, for any random variable $Z \in (-\infty, \infty]$ and any non-negative constant $x$.
Why should this hold?

Suppose $Z=1$ and $x=1$. LHS has probability 0 and RHS has probability 1.

You are right, this is a confusion caused by a typo in the PhD thesis by Richardson's student Elkouss. In fact, it should be that Z is at least 0 in the LHS. I will fix this.

A proof of the claim has been found. Using the definitions of tanh and arctanh.
\begin{equation}
- \ln \tanh \frac{z}{2} \leq x
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
\tanh \frac{z}{2} \geq e^{-x}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
\frac{e^{z/2} - e^{-z/2}}{e^{z/2} + e^{-z/2}} \geq e^{-x}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
e^{z/2} - e^{-z/2} \geq e^{-x} (e^{z/2} + e^{-z/2})
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
 e^{z} - 1 \geq e^{-x} (e^{z} + 1)
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
e^{z} - 1 \geq e^{-x} e^{z} + e^{-x}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
e^{z} - e^{-x} e^{z} \geq e^{-x} + 1
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
 e^{z} (1 - e^{-x}) \geq 1 + e^{-x}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
e^{z} \geq \frac{1 + e^{-x}}{1 - e^{-x}}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
z \geq \ln \left( \frac{1 + e^{-x}}{1 - e^{-x}} \right)
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
z \geq -\ln \tanh \frac{x}{2}
\end{equation}
